# Why Do Play Framework Form Helpers Use 'Extra' Tags?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Why do Play's Form Helpers generate the `dl`,`dt`, and `dd` tags?  They seem unnecessary.

```
   <dl class="error" id="email_field">
        <dt><label for="email">Email:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""></dd>
        <dd class="error">This field is required!</dd>
        <dd class="error">Another error</dd>
        <dd class="info">Required</dd>
        <dd class="info">Another constraint</dd>
    </dl>
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers

Comment: Hi, I can answer you that because it's my fault. When Guillaume Bort (Play creator) started the form system 3-4 years ago, he took one of my form templates (I was working next to him at the time). This is how I personally organise forms, but be aware that you can override every single template on your own.

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer it done this way?  Seems redundant.  Any plans to change this? Or maybe add-on the changes?

Comment: It's more a semantic preference than a very pragmatic choice. I'm not aware of any plan to change this.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the fast and candid answer!

Comment: @MaximeDantec means not recommended to using `@helper.inputText(userForm("name"))` :(

Answer (score 2):

Although Maxime confessed himself, remember that's just default helpers. If they were ie. just pure fields people would start to why it doesn't use some structure ;)

Besides all remember that Play allows you to create custom constructors  easily which is perfectly showed in [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers#Writing-your-own-field-constructor).