# generating html via using helpers

Tags: java, scala, playframework, play-templates, play-helpers

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    public int id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(1)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(30)
    public String firstName;
}
```

Using this class I tried to use helper:

```
@helper.inputText(userForm("firstName"),'placeholder->"First Name",'class->"textbox1",'required->"required")
```

but it generates it:

```
<dl id="firstName_field" class=" ">

    <dt><label for="firstName">firstName</label></dt>

    <dd>
    <input type="text" required="required" class="textbox1" placeholder="First Name" value="" name="firstName" id="firstName">
</dd>


        <dd class="info">Minimum length: 1</dd>

        <dd class="info">Required</dd>

        <dd class="info">Maximum length: 30</dd>

</dl>
```

My question is how to remove these:

```
    <dd class="info">Minimum length: 1</dd>

    <dd class="info">Required</dd>

    <dd class="info">Maximum length: 30</dd>
```

I don't want these extras.

I was just expecting the:

```
<input type="text" required="required" class="textbox1" placeholder="First Name" value="" name="firstName" id="firstName">
```

I am having curiosity how other developers used helpers.

Comment: See the comments in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677138/why-do-play-framework-form-helpers-use-extra-tags .It doesnt have much info. maybe it will help you.

Comment: @singhakash means can't do anything hahahaha... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you want to hide are... constraints - the same you gave as annotations to your model and/or Form class.

If you took a look into **[templating docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers#Field-constructors)** you would see, there is possibility to disable them with `'_showConstraints -> false`.

Of course you can write your own helpers and/or use direct HTML markup for generating forms.

Comment: general HTML for generating forms is recommended  or not in play framework?
i feel more comfortable with normal html

Comment: The best practice is using custom field contructors (described on the same documentation I linked) in that case at least you Don'tRepeatYourself... of course there's nothing wrong with using custom markup, but you need to handle such things as errors and constraiants (nomen omen) yourself.